# Can I parameterize the property name of a PropertyExpression using LINQ Expressions?

Tags: .net, linq, reflection, expression

Supposing I have the following LambdaExpression:

```
var itemParam = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Thing), "thing");
var someValue = "ABCXYZ123"; // value to compare

LambdaExpression lex = Expression.Lambda(
  Expression.Equal(
    Expression.Property(itemParam, "Id"), // I want ID to be a Body expression parameter
    Expression.Constant(someValue)
  ), itemParm);
```

And I want the property name (2nd parameter) in the Expression.Property(...) factory to be a parameter, how do I go about doing this?

I was hoping to see a constructor that looks like this, but it doesn't exist:

`Expresssion.Property(Expression instance, Expression propName)`

Is there some trick I can pull that can convert a parameterized ConstantExpression into the needed string or MemberInfo? Maybe I'm going about this the wrong way.

My hunch is that because these expression trees, when compiled, become lightweight IL, that member access information is required, thus, the names of members and properties must be provided when constructing expression trees.

Thanks for any tips!!

*EDIT: Wanted to add that this will be used as an argument to the Enumerable.Where(...) extension method for determining a match on a relationship between two classes / entities.*

Comment: What are you planning to do with the resulting expression? Are you planning to send it to EF/LINQ2<something> by any chance?

Comment: Actually, it's used to resolve an entity reference through user-defined keys... but eventually may be leveraged by the IQueryable provider we have. :)

Comment: Perfect - in this case, your query provider could look for your helper function (see my answer below) and do its magic accordingly. I am assuming that the capability of searching on a property identified by a string name is built into your query provider.

Comment: It's based on the IQToolkit, so yeah... lot's of the existing underpinnings and tree visitor support already exists with the ability to handle whatever methods it finds. We've added some custom visitors atop what the IQToolkit offers and expression processing like this is right at home. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expression trees represent IL structures that are *roughly* of the same kind that you see in your C#/VB.NET programs. You cannot parameterize that property expression for the same reason that you cannot "parameterize" the following code:

```
var x = new MyClass {Id = 1, Name = "hello"};
var propName = "Id";
var xId = x.propName; // <-- This will not compile
```

If you need to implement this functionality, and your expression trees are not passed to `IQueryable<T>`, you can write a helper function taking an object and a string, and returning value of that object's property identified by the string; then you can use `Expression.Call` to invoke that helper function into the expression tree that you are building.

Comment: This has me thinking in the right direction. The idea of changing the property access to a helper method call seems reasonable. I think what I might do is create a cache of expressions based on the criteria that affect what the property name is. In this case, it's a key lookup for a type. (Some types will have different, or even compound properties for their key). So, for a given type, I'll create the expression needed to do the compare. BTW, this eventually winds up being passed as the argument to Enumerable.Where(...) ext. method. Thanks!!!